# why view hides behind status bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view

if we try to add view to self.window 
[window addSubView:someviewcontroler.view];

why the view is hiden behind the status bar upto 20 pixel?
I found the solution to hide the status bar or set view.frame.origin.y to 20.
but I want to know why it hides.
Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

That's no longer the way you'll want to show your root `UIViewController`. (it used to be, but it got changed a while back... <strike>possibly iOS 5?</strike> in iOS 4)

To prevent the issue try using
`window.rootViewController = someviewcontroller`

Comment: That was introduced in iOS 4.

Comment: Whew, time sure flies then. I knew it was a while back. :)